# Opening every file in a specific folder

Tags: excel, vba

i'm making a code for Excel that opens every file in a specific folder. When the file is open I like to add a button to each of these files at the same location. I made this code shown as below. but somehow I get this error:

> Run-Time Error '1004': Unable to get the Add property of the
>   OLEObjects class

The code breaks on the line where it says: set addbutton = etc...

Does anyone know why?

My Code:

```
Dim AddButton As OLEObject

Set AddButton = 
Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("Planning").OLEObjects.add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, 
DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=3.52941176470588, Top:=106.764705882353, 
Width:=47.6470588235294, Height:=24.7058823529412)

With AddButton
.Name = "SortPlanner"
.OnAction = "SortPersonalPlanner"

With .Object
    .Caption = "Sorteren"
    .BackColor = &HFFFFFF
End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, use `.Buttons.Add` instead of `.OLEObjects.add`

```
Set AddButton = Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("Planning").Buttons.Add(3.53, 106.76, 47.65, 24.71)

With AddButton
    .Characters.Text = "Sorteren"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .OnAction = "SortPersonalPlanner"
End With
```

Comment: then you should add `Dim AddButton As Button` at the beginning

Comment: Ok, thanks but then it is not an ActiveX object right? So can I make the background of the bottom white? As far as I know a bottom can not have any format right?

Comment: @JellevanderHeijden, Yes think you are right about the background color,
I tried your code without the `Set AddButton = ... ` and just directly `Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("Planning").OLEObjects.add ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, 
DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=3.52941176470588, Top:=106.764705882353, 
Width:=47.6470588235294, Height:=24.7058823529412`

This will add a button but i could not get the `.OnAction = "SortPersonalPlanner"` to be added.

Comment: Thanks @LokiPatera That seems to do it! but underneath that line I use With AddButton to assign a name and an action. This will not work now because I dit not declare the AddButton. How can I solve this?

Comment: **Loop trough all the OLEobjects until you find yours**
`For Each obj In Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("Planning").OLEObjects

    If obj.programID = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then

        .Name = "SortPlanner"

        .OnAction = "SortPersonalPlanner"

            With .Object
                .Caption = "Sorteren"
                .BackColor = &HFFFFFF
            End With
    End If
Next obj`

Comment: @LokiPatera Thanks, i did a bit different.Now I get a error message when reaching .OnAction. it says Unable to get the OnAction property of the OLEObjects class. this is the code I use:  `Dim obj As OLEObject
Set obj = Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("Planning").OLEObjects("Commandbutton1")

With obj

    .OnAction = "SortPersonalPlanner"

        With .Object
        .Caption = "Sorteren"
        .BackColor = &HFFFFFF
        .OnAction = "SortPersonalPlanner"
    End With
End With`

Comment: @JellevanderHeijden Yeah, that's why i suggested the alternative solution, without coloring the background of the button. Hope you can live without the extra color .